# Android camera - Is it possible to restrict image size?

Tags: java, android, android-camera

I am working on this app On android phone,
On newer phones the images that are captured are sometimes 10MB -> 8000 x 6000  pixels.
And this is an overkill for our application and usage. we need a smaller image size

This is the code that captures the images,
Is it possible to restrict the camera to a specific dimensions ?
lets say maximum image size 4032 x 3024
Or
Is it possible to restrict the camera to a maximum image size 3MB
Thank you!

```
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
            ...
        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                                                  "com.example.android.fileprovider",
                                                  photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set an EXTRA_SIZE_LIMIT.  This is the maximum size in bytes.  Now its possible the camera app will ignore this flag (it's a request, not an enforced value), but it *should* work for most camera apps.